# ifelse() used with all() on multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr

I have this data:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~a, ~b , ~c , ~d,
  0, 0, 0, 0,
  1, 1, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 1
)
```

and would like to get this output - if there is a zero in all columns `TRUE` is returned:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
      a     b     c     d new  
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
1     0     0     0     0 TRUE 
2     1     1     0     0 FALSE
3     0     1     0     0 FALSE
4     0     0     0     1 FALSE
```

I tried this and it works:

```
data %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(new = ifelse(all(c(a,b,c,d) == 0) , TRUE, FALSE))
```

But what if I have many more columns? I would NOT want to write something like this:

```
data %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(new = ifelse(all(c(a,b,c,d,e,f,.......z) == 0) , TRUE, FALSE))
```

Is there a better way of writing this?

Note: I am using dplyr 0.8.3

Comment: `!do.call(pmax, data)`

Comment: (1) `all` returns length 1, so `ifelse` is a waste here; just do `new = +all(...)`. (2), as @d.b just said, you can expand with `do.call` for varying number of columns (and likely without `rowwise`, which can be horrible performance).

Comment: You can also use `c_across` : `data %>%  rowwise() %>% mutate(new = all(c_across() == 0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `rowwise`. Using @d.b's `do.call` suggestion:

```r
data %>%
  mutate(new = do.call(pmax, .) == 0)
# # A tibble: 4 x 5
#       a     b     c     d new  
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
# 1     0     0     0     0 TRUE 
# 2     1     1     0     0 FALSE
# 3     0     1     0     0 FALSE
# 4     0     0     0     1 FALSE
```

That works when you need all columns. If instead you need a subset, then you can use the somewhat new `across`:

```r
data %>%
  mutate(new = do.call(pmax, across(a:d)) == 0)
```

If you don't have `across`, try this base-R method for selecting a range of columns:

```r
data %>%
  mutate(new = do.call(pmax, subset(., select = a:d)) == 0)
```

Comment: Is there an alternative to `across`? I am on an older version of dplyr

Comment: As some future advice: there are a lot of changes in the newest release of `dplyr`, and many of the answers you'll get on questions will likely touch on those new features. Examples include: `across(.)`, tidylang-like things in G.Grothendieck's answer (`!!!`), etc. The same goes for older versions of `tidyr`, `purrr`, etc. It's fine if you stay on those versions (completely fine, btw), I suggest that you should indicate your specific versions in the question to avoid less-helpful answers. Granted, others with your problem may also want the modern solutions, but ... you first :-)

Answer (score 2):

One base R option is using `rowSums` instead of `ifelse`

```
data$new <- rowSums(abs(data))==0
```

which gives

```
> data
# A tibble: 4 x 5
      a     b     c     d new  
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
1     0     0     0     0 TRUE 
2     1     1     0     0 FALSE
3     0     1     0     0 FALSE
4     0     0     0     1 FALSE
```

Comment: Instead of `abs` also `rowSums(data!=0)==0` could be used.

Answer (score 1):

Here are several approaches.  The first two require a recent version of dplyr, the third works with older versions of dplyr too and the fourth uses only base R.

`cur_data()` refers to the current group. See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/context.html  Three exclamation marks `!!!` is from rlang.  It is imported by dplyr and causes the columns of its argument to be passed as separate arguments to `pmax`.  In the last two solutions `apply(data == 0, 1, all)` applies `all` to each row of `data == 0`.

```
data %>% rowwise %>% mutate(new = all(cur_data() == 0)) %>% ungroup

data %>% mutate(new = !pmax(!!!.))

data %>% mutate(new = apply(. == 0, 1, all)) # older versions of dpylr ok

transform(data, new = apply(data == 0, 1, all))  # base R
```